# Adjustable Voltage Regulator Causing Fixed Regulator to Change Voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, potentiometer

I have a center tap transformer that supplies 28VAC to this board. The center tap is connected to my ground plane. When no potentiometer is connected all fixed regulators work as expected, but once the pots are added to the 317 and 337 everything gets crazy. The voltage of the 7812 is no longer outputting 12V and is now putting out around 11V when the pot is at 1K ohm. If I reduce the pot to its minimum, things get worse and the the 7812 puts out 10V. If I remove the pot from circuit both the 7812 and 7805 work fine. Also if I power all regulators using a DC supply everything works as expected.

[image: schematic]

Comment: What frequency is the source? C1, C3 of 0.33uF/.22uf is very small for 50 Hz or 60 Hz.

Comment: I think that circuit might catch fire with that input voltage. Where's the centre-tapped transformer?

Comment: 60Hz. It's plugged into the wall with a transformer in front of the circuit.

Comment: What is the output of the wall transformer?

Comment: 120VAC in 28VAC out

Comment: @garretts228 Don't label things as 120 VAC if they're actually 28 VAC! That's still pretty high for using a linear regulator down to 12 V afterward, though; I'd suggest a 12 or 15 V secondary instead.

Comment: Your feedback resistors are way too low; you're wasting a lot of power in them that you don't need to. Try increasing them by an order of magnitude or two.

Answer (score 3):

A filter capacitor must be installed from bridge positive to ground and from bridge negative to ground. 470 microfarad or larger. These are needed to smooth the full wave rectified output pulses from the bridge. Increase the value until the dc output ripple from the regulators disappears.

Measure the output ripple of the regulators at full load. If increasing the capacitance cannot remove the ripple, then the input voltage must be increased.

Comment: No smoothing caps were indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two BFCs (big fat capacitors) one each across C1 and C3. Something like 1000uF/50V but it depends on how much current you want to allow for and how much ripple can be tolerated before the regulators start to drop out at minimum allowable mains voltage.

Also you are probably exceeding the maximum input voltages of the regulators, at least one is only rated for 40V and your peak voltage with a light load will probably exceed that by 10 or 20%. That's assuming your transformer is 28:28VAC. If it's actually 14:14 (28VAC center-tapped), ignore the above. If it isn't center-tapped, your circuit won't work.

Comment: Its 28VAC center tapped. Smoothing cap ended up being the problem. Works perfect now.

Comment: Great. I hope you used two smoothing caps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ADJ pin, if you are getting oscillations then the pot is creating an unintentional filter. You may need to find a better way to filter the ADJ when the pot is added

Answer (score 0):

I added two two 1000uF smoothing caps to the circuit and all is well now. One from the positive output of the rectifier to ground, and one from the negative output of the rectifier to ground. I guess the circuit worked under no load without the 317 and 337 having the pots hooked up, because the input caps for the regulators weren't being fully depleted. Once the pots were added to circuit, it completed the circuit resulting in depletion of the input caps which sent all regulators into drop out. I hate that I missed something so obvious, but you live and you learn. Anyways this was my class project for linear and I am now done with school since this was the last thing for me to complete. [image]

Comment: Are those dipped tantalum capacitors? They'll *work*, but eugh, tantalum caps always feel wrong in projects like this. Way too risky when you don't actually need the size reduction over aluminum ones.